GSAP slider auto scrolling + draggable + scrollbar
I need to create a timeline that must adhere to the following behaviors:

Both the timeline and the slider must scroll automatically
The user should be able to take control of the scrolling with the slider
When the user finishes dragging the slider, the timeline AND the slider should resume their automatic scrolling

Today, I have an issue. Everything works well in auto-scroll, but as soon as I drag the slider, it stays frozen and doesn't start moving again.
I don't understand why, onDragEnd, my autoScroll method restarts fine but the .to related to the slider doesn't 
If anyone has a solution, I'm all ears,
Thanks in advance.
Here a small demo: https://codepen.io/Arthur-Vera/pen/qBwooYY
import gsap from "gsap";
import Draggable from "gsap/Draggable";
import {InertiaPlugin} from "gsap/InertiaPlugin";
import ScrollTrigger from "gsap/ScrollTrigger";

gsap.registerPlugin(Draggable, InertiaPlugin, ScrollTrigger);

class Frise {
    constructor() {
        this.blockFrise = document.querySelector(".block-frise");
        if (!this.blockFrise) return;

        // Frise elements
        this.frise = document.querySelector(".frise");
        this.friseWidth = this.frise.offsetWidth;
        this.friseItems = gsap.utils.toArray(".frise__item");
        this.friseItemsWrapper = document.querySelector(".frise__items");
        this.friseItemsWrapperWidth = this.friseItems[0].offsetWidth * this.friseItems.length;

        // Navigation elements
        this.dragWidth = this.friseItemsWrapperWidth - this.friseWidth;
        this.friseNavigation = document.querySelector(".frise-navigation");
        this.friseNavigationWidth = this.friseNavigation.offsetWidth;
        this.grabCursor = document.querySelector(".grab-cursor");
        this.gradCursorWidth = this.grabCursor.offsetWidth;
        this.ratio = this.dragWidth / (this.friseNavigationWidth - this.gradCursorWidth);

        // window.addEventListener('resize', this.handleResize.bind(this));

        this.init();
    }

    createGrid() {
        let numberOfItems = this.friseItems.length;
        this.friseItemsWrapper.style.gridTemplateColumns = `repeat(${numberOfItems}, 1fr)`;
        this.friseItems.forEach((item, index) => {
            item.style.gridColumn = `${index + 1} / span 1`;
        });
    }

    friseAppear() {
        gsap.set(this.friseItems, {opacity: 0, x: 100});
        ScrollTrigger.create({
            trigger: this.frise,
            start: "top 80%",
            onEnter: () => {
                gsap.to(this.friseItems, {opacity: 1, x: 0, duration: 0.5, stagger: 0.1});
            },
        });
    }

    handleFrise() {
        const friseMove = () => {
            const tl = gsap.timeline({});
            let cursorPosition = this.grabCursor.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            let frisePosition = this.friseNavigation.getBoundingClientRect().left;
            let dragDistance = cursorPosition - frisePosition;

            tl.to(this.friseItemsWrapper, {
                x: -dragDistance * this.ratio,
                duration: 0.5,
                ease: "power2.out",
            });
        }


        Draggable.create(this.grabCursor, {
            type: "x",
            bounds: this.friseNavigation,
            onDrag: () => {
                friseMove();
            },
            onDragEnd: () => {},
        });
    }

    init() {
        this.createGrid();
        this.friseAppear();
        this.handleFrise();
    }
}

export default Frise;

